# Retaining DDL Selected Value from Validation Errors on Submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation

Trying to figure out if I have painted myself into a corner.

I have and ASP.NET MVC application form where I dynamically change a group of questions based upon a dropdown box selection.  So the user will see a generic form, has the ability to refine the request and as they select different options, I use a change event on the dropdown to then show or hide divs for the section of questions.

My JavaScript:

```
                $(function () {
                    $('div.login').hide();
                    $('div.normal').show();//by default, display the normal div
                    $('div.login.SignUp').show();//by default, display the normal div
                    $("#ddl_select").change(function () {
                        var currentdiv = $("div." + $(this).val());
                        currentdiv.show(); //based on the selected value to show the relevant div.

                        $('div.login').not(currentdiv).hide(); //hide other div
                    });
                });
```

My Dropdown box:

```html
    <select id="ddl_select" name="userSelection">
          <option value="SignUp">Sign Up</option>
          <option value="ReportABug">Report a Bug</option>
          <option value="Feature">Feature Request</option>
    </select>
```

and then in my .cshtml I will have my divs named as such:

```html
<div class="login SignUp">
     <div class="form-row pt-2 px-3 pb-3">
        Form field details here 
    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="login ReportABug">
                    <div class="form-row pt-2 px-3 pb-3">
        Form field 1 details here   
    </div>
                    <div class="form-row pt-2 px-3 pb-3">
        Form field 2 details here   
    </div>
                    <div class="form-row pt-2 px-3 pb-3">
        Form field 3 details here   
    </div>
            </div>
```

etc.

All and all this works for changing the display of the form, but when I start adding in validation like required, string lengths, etc. The validations fire properly, but I lose the selection I was on. So if SignUp is my default section exposed, but the user selects ReportABug, fills out the form and submits, after the validation rules on the model are fired, if there are any failures, they are returned back and actually display properly, but the page returns back to its initial state (SignUp) being initial display.  If the user selects ReportABug again from the dropdown, the previous data and error messages are there and properly displayed, I am just trying to figure in how from retain the selection and have so the user retains the selection.

Maybe I have to set a session variable anytime the validation is fired and then check where that exists etc.